# 403 forbidden when permission are 777

Tags: apache, permissions

I have a script on my server that is trying to access the uploaded folder on my server. When I run the script I'm getting a 403 forbidden error when the script tries to access the uploaded folder even though I have the permission set for uploaded to be wwww-data:www-data and 777. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have any rules set in config or .htaccess in side that uploaded folder? And how is the script being ran? Is it from the web server or a user?

Comment: no rules set in config or .htaccess. The script is https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload and is running on the webserver. The user clicks upload photos, it brings up a light box where they can upload a picture from their PC. The lightbox pops and they can choose an image, but when the user clicks 'Start' to start the upload it fails and says Not Found. When I look at the Console Log in chrome its showing as 403 forbidden on the /uploaded/ folder.  :(

Answer (score 3):

Check the permissions on the whole path.

If you want to access /dir1/dir2/dir3/file, you need read permissions on file, but also execute permissions on dir1, dir2, and dir3.

Permissions work a little different for directories than for files. Write permission means you can create files in that directory. Read means you can list the files in that directory. Execute means you can use that directory as part of a path.

In this case, if the permissions for that specific file are correct, then you need to check the directories that make up the path.

Alternatively, it could be an Apache config issue, but I would check the directories first.